# Rails 5.1 and Geocoder: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using Geocoder to get coordinates for an adress:

```
location.rb

geocoded_by :address      
after_validation :geocode
```

It doesn't save because of the OpsenSSL Error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate
verify failed):
```

I use Nominatim as API. Did I miss something?

**Update**

That is an excerpt of the output of bundle install

```
Using geocoder 1.5.0

Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 82 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: I think you have problem with installing your gems. Did your bundle install command finished okay? Do you using windows OS?

Comment: Everything seemed okay. Reinstalled it, still installation is normal but it gives me this error. Yes, I'm using windows 7.

Comment: can you show me result when you run in your console bundle install?

Comment: I couldn't show the whole output because of code-limitiations of stack overflow.

Comment: show the last 20 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved through

```
gem update --system
```